# Why my code isn't displaying last writeline

Tags: c#

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] massiiv = new int[20];
        int sum = 0;
        Random r = new Random();

        for (int arv = 1; arv <= 20; arv++)
        {
            if (massiiv[arv] % 2 == 0)
                sum = sum + massiiv[arv];

            Console.WriteLine("{0}", r.Next(100, 200));
        }

        Console.WriteLine("{0}", sum);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

So I want to display sum of even numbers in my array, but the `WriteLine` isn't displaying at all.  I need to form a one dimension array consisting of 20 random ints between 100 and 200 and I want console to print sum of all even numbers in array.

Comment: You don't assign anything to elements of `massiiv` array. So `sum` will be always 0.

Comment: but i need random int-s, i cant assign anything to my array? i'm beginner actually..

Comment: In C# indexing starts from 0, so for array with length 20 you need to start for from 0 and end at 19. Assign elements of massiiv one by one with r.Next(100, 200) or r.Next(100, 201), depending on whether you want up to 200 inclusive or exclusive;

Answer (score 0):

you see, when you create an array, that does not put numbers in the array. if you want the array to be filled with number, you should initiate the array with numbers. if you want random numbers, you should put random numbers in it.

you did

```
Random r = new Random();
```

that initiate a Random class but does nothing to the array `massiiv`

you need to put random numbers in the array like so:

```
for (int arv = 1; arv <= 20; arv++)
{
   massiiv[arv] = r.NextInt(100) + 100;
}
```

that will put random numbers in the array

```
r.NextInt(100)
```

create a random number between 0-100, and so

```
r.NextInt(100) + 100
```

create a random number between 100-200

Answer (score 0):

You array consists of 20 zeros. Also this code throws exception because there is no `massiiv[20]` element. Array with 20 elements has indexes 0-19. It should be `for (int arv = 0; arv < 20; arv++)`